# The Definition of Insanity

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You wake up, still dizzy from the blow to your head. You have no idea what they want from you, where you are and how you got here, but you know one thing: you want to get out! Looking around you see four walls, one with a poem and three with dots written on them (click on the images to see a larger version).

[image: North Wall] [image: East Wall] [image: South Wall] [image: West Wall]

You also notice a piece of chalk and a small note lying next to you on the ground (click to enlarge):

[image: Note]

---

***What do you write on the walls to get out?***

---

*Hint 1:*

> Seriously, the ninth to the fourteenth line: very interesting...
>  (1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)

*Hint 1 (2):*

> `. . . . ,  . . .  . . . .`
>  Here, one hint

Comment: I'm assuming the water mark on the paper is *not* part of the puzzle?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That's right, the water mark isn't part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Wu33o Should ENDEAVOUR be ENDEAVOR? Typo or intentional?

Comment: @Techidiot Endeavour is intentional (it's the non-US version). I've double-checked everything and there are no typos.

Comment: @Wu33o One more thing, are you missing a word in the line **GRAMMAR IS INCORRECT AND METRE MESSY, WRONGLY PLACED** ? See my answer.

Comment: @Techidiot You were missing 'OR'. I've edited your answer to include it.

Comment: @Wu33o Thanks. Missed the word somehow I guess

Comment: @Wu33o Was the hint about telling that we need to fill the blanks? If yes, its already known. If its about finding relations, its fine :)

Comment: @Techidiot I assumed that you know that you have to fill in the blanks :)

Comment: @Wu33o: Can you confirm that there is some kind of logical way of arranging the letters found into the sentences? For the hint sentence, Techidiot and I haven't been able to find such an arrangement.

Comment: Joke answer: Break the chalk into two halves. Put the two halves together to make a whole. Put the hole on the wall and get out. :P

Comment: @edderiofer - I just hope it was that simple :D

Comment: @Wu33o: Can you please tell us whether it's just a matter of anagramming once you've found the right letters for each line, or if there's some kind of system to it?

Comment: @Wu33o: Is there any hint you can provide that doesn't spoil it completely, but gives a gentle nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Partial(Collection of the data mostly)

> This is just a collection of data which might help fellow puzzlers take it ahead.
>  The text version of the note is -
>
>  A LITTLE ATTENTION HERE IS VERY IMPORTANT
>  RIGHT INGREDIENTS ARE PRESENT, HOWEVER SHORTENED
>  BEGIN, COMMENCE QUICKLY, SOLVE, PROGRESS
>  TO BE ACHIEVING WISDOM, POWER AND SUCCESS
>  MAYBE YOU NOTICE SOME WORDS ARE ODDLY PLACED
>  OR GRAMMAR IS INCORRECT AND METRE MESSY, WRONGLY PACED
>  LOWER EXPECTATIONS AND ENJOY A MYSTERY
>  DISENTANGLE AND DECIPHER; THE REST IS HISTORY
>
>
>  TO EXIT, THERE IS ONE THING YOU NEED
>  A SINGLE WORD AND ONE WILL BE FREED
>  MIDDLE, OR CENTRAL, IS ESSENTIAL HERE
>  MAKE EVERYTHING ELSE DISAPPEAR
>  IF YOU MUST CHOOSE, USE A PAIR
>  IF THERE ARE NONE, ONE MUST NOT CARE
>
>
>  YOU OUGHT TO BE QUICK, OR SUFFER FOREVER
>  BE WISER, SWIFTLY FINISHING YOUR ENDEAVOUR
>
>  And the numbers are -
>
>  4 2 3 1 2 3 4
>  3 1 2 4 2 1
>  4 2 4 3 1
>  1 3 4 3 3 1 2
>  3 1 4 4 1 4 3 4
>  3 3 1 2 2 4 2 3 3
>  3 3 2 4 1 1
>  3 4 1 3 4 1 2
>  3 4 4 1 4 2 2 1
>  1 2 3 4 4 3 1 4
>  4 1 2 3 4 2
>  3 2 1 2
>  1 3 2 4 1 3 2
>  3 4 4 1 4 2 2 4
>  4 2 2 1 2 1 2 3
>  1 3 4 2 1 1
>
>
>  1 2 2 2 1 1
>  2 1 1 2 1 2
>  2 1 2 1 2 2
>  2 2 1 2 2 1
>
>
>  1 1
>  1 1 1 1 1
>
>
>  The numbers seem to correspond to the text. By relating the numbers with text we get good relations
>
>
>  A - 4
>  LITTLE- 2
>  ATTENTION - 3
>  HERE - 1
>  IS - 2
>  VERY-3
>  IMPORTANT-4
>
>  RIGHT - 3
>  INGREDIENTS - 2
>  ARE-1
>  PRESENT-4
>  HOWEVER-2
>  SHORTENED-1
>
>  BEGIN-4
>  COMMENCE-2
>  QUICKLY-4
>  SOLVE-3
>  PROGRESS-1
>
>  TO-1
>  BE-3
>  ACHIEVING-4
>  WISDOM-3
>  POWER-3
>  AND-1
>  SUCCESS-2
>
>  MAYBE-3
>  YOU-1
>  NOTICE-4
>  SOME-4
>  WORDS-1
>  ARE-4
>  ODDLY-3
>  PLACED-4
>
>  OR-3
>  GRAMMAR-3
>  IS-1
>  INCORRECT-2
>  AND-2
>  METRE-4
>  MESSY-2
>  WRONGLY-3
>  PACED-3
>
>  LOWER-3
>  EXPECTATIONS-3
>  AND-2
>  ENJOY-4
>  A-1
>  MYSTERY-1
>
>  DISENTANGLE-3
>  AND-4
>  DECIPHER-1
>  THE-3
>  REST-4
>  IS-1
>  HISTORY-2
>
>  TO-3
>  EXIT-4
>  THERE-4
>  IS-1
>  ONE-4
>  THING-2
>  YOU-2
>  NEED-1
>
>  A-1
>  SINGLE-2
>  WORD-3
>  AND-4
>  ONE-4
>  WILL-3
>  BE-1
>  FREED-4
>
>  MIDDLE-4
>  OR-1
>  CENTRAL-2
>  IS-3
>  ESSENTIAL-4
>  HERE-2
>
>  MAKE-3
>  EVERYTHING-2
>  ELSE-1
>  DISAPPEAR-2
>
>  IF-1
>  YOU-3
>  MUST-2
>  CHOOSE-4
>  USE-1
>  A-3
>  PAIR-2
>
>  IF-3
>  THERE-4
>  ARE-4
>  NONE-1
>  ONE-4
>  MUST-2
>  NOT-2
>  CARE-4
>
>
>  YOU-4
>  OUGHT-2
>  TO-2
>  BE-1
>  QUICK-2
>  OR-1
>  SUFFER-2
>  FOREVER-3
>
>  BE-1
>  WISER-3
>  SWIFTLY-4
>  FINISHING-2
>  YOUR-1
>  ENDEAVOUR-1
>
>  Also, the hint speaks the same language
>  Seriously, the ninth to the fourteenth line: very interesting...
>  (1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)
>
>  Seriously-1
>  the-1
>  ninth-1
>  to=1
>  the-1
>  fourteenth-1
>  line-1
>  very-1
>  interesting-1

Next Step

> Next step would be to fill in the blanks for the first image using the relation above where I's stuck -
>  - - # - - - # - - - - -, # - - - -, # - - # - - - - - -
>  - - - - - - - - # - - - - - # - - - - - - - - # - - - - # - - - - - # - - - -
>  - - - - - # - - - - - - - , # -- # - - - # - - - - - # - - - - -
>  - - - - - - - # - - - # - - - - - , # - - - - - - - # - - - - - # - - - - - - - - -
>
>
>
>  Some possibilities are applying Rot-n to the word and take the first/middle letter. Second possibility could be to take the central part of the word and skip others. Third could be take two words, combine them and take the central part. Finding the relation is the key for filling the blanks.

Further Findings

> Hint 1 (2) gives an example to fill the blank. I am assuming it to have a logic of taking the middle letters. If its even length, take a pair and if its of length 2 or 1, skip it(Found by @Levieux). Doing that we get  -
>
>  *Seriously(O), the(H) ninth(N) to the(H) fourteenth(TE) line:(IN) very(ER) interesting.(E)*
>
>
>  the **(H)**
>  very **(ER)**
>  interesting **(E)**
>  Seriously **(O)**
>  ninth **(N)**
>  fourteenth **(E)**
>  the **(H)**
>  line: **(IN)**
>  fourteenth **(T)**
>
>
>  Rearranging the words gives the answer as **HERE ONE HINT**. But, I am still not sure if I am on the right track and if I am guessing the logic right.
>
>
>  We know now, that the numbers are line numbers. Hence grouping the words by their line numbers and taking the centers of all of them gives
>
>  ERRTGRNORTIPEELSSONOUA
>
>  TTDEMECRNSNTIONGTERYTPUSAIUSOGIFFS
>
>  NERGLSDWYDMNCWTATHORILAKOES
>
>  RSGCETIOMRACTJNESXIEBBBEDDNOOERNAROF
>
>  Which fits the dots(119 total). But its impossible to create words out of them without knowing the logic.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with this. I came to the same conclusions a minute ago. It also works for the entire text. Words with length 1 or 2 -> skip. Words with even length -> take middle 2, words with odd length -> take middle 1.

Comment: So "to the" becomes 'h', because "to" -> "" and "the" -> "h". I have no idea how to order them so at the moment I only have an anagram to the first (119 characters) part.

Comment: @Levieux Oh yes. The characters count. Yes, rearranging them is what I am thinking of.

Comment: @Levieux What if its simple taking middle of the whole sentence, breaking it down, taking middle again and repeating again and again? The title clues to doing something again and again.

Comment: no must be done word by word. Then you get to the first dotted picture. Doing it again leads to the second, and then finally to the third. The numbers refer to the lines btw.

Comment: Oh, and about the characters, *Seriously,* yields to **ou** ? considering comma?

Comment: No, without the comma. First line is something like Anagram(errtgrnortinou) + "so please"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53681/discussion-between-techidiot-and-levieux).